# Shopping Cart magento not updated

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, cart

my Magento store does not update the shopping cart when the number of items is changed, it remains only 1 fee for each product, I tried to fix this by placing...

```
 <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost')?> " method="post">
            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

but have not been successful , I'm working on magento 1.9.2.2 , greatly appreciate the help of the community , thanks.

EDIT - Now I realized that updates only when a higher number is entered 32, the strange thing is that I have no rule or something

Comment: `< ? php` is not the same as `<?php`, nor is `$ this` the same as `$this` - stop spacing your code like that!

Comment: @RobbieAverill Excuse me, but spaces were generated by the editor of StackOverflow , I had not noticed this.